# Import Excel table in PowerBuiler via Data Pipeline

Tags: excel, powerbuilder

This error occurs when trying to view table data in ODBC profile.

```
    SQLSTATE = 37000
    [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
    SELECT categoryid, categoryname, description FROM sheet$northwind__modded__for_sync_via_ms_access_#accdb
```

Is there issue with '#' symbol?
It is necessary for me to use Data Pipeline

Comment: Are you getting this error in the DB Painter or when you try to run the pipeline?

Comment: In both, in DB Painter and when executing pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `DelimiterIdentifier = 'Yes'` in the DBParm when creating your database profile in Powerbuilder.

[Link](http://www.sybase.co.uk/detail?id=44462)